# Where can I find style guides for web apps online?

Tags: web-app, style, style-guide

I am developing a style guide for a web application. I would like to find some good example style guides online to refer to. I am not having much luck with Google. What are some good resources to help get me started?

Comment: Do you need CSS/Visual Design Style guide..?

Comment: Do you mean a visual style guide, a user interface style guide, or one about the copy of the app?

Answer (score 6):

Would these work for you?

Here's a few others:
[Web Style Guide 3.0](http://www.webstyleguide.com/wsg3/index.html)

[Skype Brand Book](http://www.issuu.com/bondo/docs/skype_brand_book_-_look)

[Android Developer Style Guide](http://developer.android.com/design/style/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Web app style guides are very rare... I've found by a research some time ago a good style guide for web apps. Hope it helps.

http://developers.sun.com/docs/web-app-guidelines/uispec4_0/01-introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

The [Ubuntu web design guidelines](http://design.canonical.com/brand/D.%20Ubuntu%20Web%20Guidelines.pdf) [PDF] covers from layout to typography of the Ububtu community sites.

Answer (score 1):

http://styleguides.io is a new **HUGE** resource for all things style guides:

- Articles
- Books
- Podcasts
- Talks/Slides
- Tools
- Examples

Check it out!